# Substring match by reqular expression

Tags: regex

I am not much familiar in regular expression, I wanted to do the following comparison by using regular expression.

Source word is : Hello124

In a list, I have following strings

Hello12

Hello

Hel

Hel123

Her

the output I want is ( Hello12, Hello, Hel ). i.e from source sting, I will reduce last char one by one and find the match in the list. Please let me know, Is that possible to use regular expression to optimize this functionality?

I am using C++ with stl::tr1 library.

Comment: Why don't you just test for substrings?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
^H(?:e(?:l(?:l(?:o(?:1(?:24?)?)?)?)?)?)?$
```

But in most languages it would be easier just to evaluate `query.StartsWith(word)` for each word.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I have tested it and its working. But how do we construct this kind expression for different string dynamically?

Comment: Suppose If I want only Hello12 instead of other substring, since it is matched with maximum length? Please let me know how to modify this?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can solve this problem by using regular expressions, for example using the following: `h|he|hel|hell|hello|hello1|hello12|hello124`.

However, this is not very nice and an overkill. As far as I know, every language supporting regex also supports querying for substrings (you may want to look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28string_functions%29#substring1) if you find yours).

Comment: Thanks, phimuemue. Currently I am using std::string find method to search the substring, because I assume that regular expression will take less time to compare and reduce one iteration to erasing the last char. Please suggest me that is this right way to address this problem or use find method?

Comment: @user1001870, I personally would tend to use find (or any equivalent) instead of a regular expression since you are only interested in whether one string is a prefix of another.